# To construct a set with a limit point.

Tags: analysis

I learned how to construct a Cantor Set, and I am asked to do the following.

"Construct a bounded set with exactly 3 limit points."

Since the Cantor set contains infinitely many points, I don't think something like it will not work.
But this is the only thing that I have learned from the book that tells me anything about constructing a set that has a limit point.

I am also considering the interval $[0,1]$ and constructing a set so that the limit points are $\{0,1/2,1\}$.

If possible, I would like to see more than one simple examples because I am new to analysis and I have no teacher. It's very tough.

Comment: Can you construct a bounded set with exactly *one* limit point?

Comment: Or to make it a little bit clearer, to solve this problem, just answer the following 3 questions: **1. **How would you construct a set contained within $[0; 1]$ that has $0$ as a limit point? **2. **How would you construct a set contained within $[0; 1]$ that has $\dfrac{1}{2}$ as a limit point? **3. **How would you construct a set contained within $[0; 1]$ that has $\left\{0; \dfrac{1}{2}; 1 \right\}$ as limit points?

Comment: For example, Let E_0 = [0,1]. Now let E_1 = (1/2,1],... E_n = (1/(n+1),1]. I want to say that 1 is a limit point if the infinite intersection of E_i s are taken.

Comment: The solution is probably much easier than you think.

Comment: [This StackExchange question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74632/given-closed-c-subseteq-mathbbr-find-a-sequence-with-subsequences-converge) is concerned with realizing any specified nonempty closed set as the set of subsequence limit points of some sequence, which should be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, everyone.  But I'm not really getting there. 

I want to say that taking the infinite subsets of [0,1/n),[2/n,2/(n+1)],(2/(n+1),1] leads to having 0,1/2 and 1 as a limit point, but I don't think it works like that.  Furthermore, I don't know how to prove so.

Comment: *But I'm not really getting there.* O-K, then [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336373/intuition-for-omega-omega/336929#336929) should be of much greater help than the last StackExchange question I cited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What are the limit points of $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\middle|\ n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$?

Comment: I would like to say that 0 is the limit point. I'm sorry, but I don't know how that helps me.

Comment: @hyg17 And if you know the limit points of $A$ and $B$ can you say something about the limit points of $A\cup B$?

Comment: Would it be the limit points of A and B ?

Comment: And does this help you to construct a set with exactly three limit points?

Comment: So, if A={1/n},B={1/2+1/n},B={1+1/n}, their union will be a set with three limit points? That sounds too easy.

Comment: It is that easy. And it is not much more difficult to alter it so that it is contained $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 7):

Construct a set with exactly one limit point and then add two distinct copies of it; let me be more clear: you'll surely agree with the fact that $\{0\} \cup \{{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} ^{*}}\}$ has only one limit point. Thus if we repeat twice a translation we'll get what we're looking for: $(\{0\} \cup \{{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} ^{*}}\}) \sqcup (\{2\} \cup \{{\frac{1}{n}+2 : n \in \mathbb{N} ^{*}}\}) \sqcup (\{4\} \cup \{{\frac{1}{n} +4: n \in \mathbb{N} ^{*}}\})$.

Answer (score 3):

Take a sequence $\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $0$, another sequence 
$\{ b_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $\frac{1}{2}$, and another sequence 
$\{ c_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $1$. Then just take the set 
$$
   S
:= \{ a_n,b_n,c_n; n \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
to be their union. By definition $0,\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ will be limit points. For example, you can let 
$a_n := \frac{1}{n}$, $b_n := \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^n}$, $c_n := 1 - \frac{1}{n!}$. This choice also conforms to your wish that $S \subseteq [0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

> "Construct a bounded set with exactly 3 limit points."

consider this set:
$$\{0.1,\space 0.2,\space0.3,\space\space0.11,\space0.22,\space0.33,\space\space0.111,\space0.222,\space0.333,\space\space0.1111,\space0.2222,\space0.3333,...\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$A=\left\{\frac ab\;\bigg|\; a,b\in\mathbb N, a=1\text{ or }a=b-1\text{ or }b=2a\pm1\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$X=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\::\:|z|=1-\frac{1}{n},n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}, \arg z\in\{0,\frac{2}{3}\pi,\frac{4}{3}\pi\}\right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

{1/n ; n belongs to N} U {(n+1)/n ; n belongs to N} U {(2n+1)/n ; n belongs to N}

this is an infinite set with 3 limit points {0,1,2}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).